# MSSQL Master db singleuser in sys.databases but multiuser in sp_helpdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, master-system-database

After opening SSMS, I have found that the **master** database on one of our production servers is in **Single User** mode.

Result of `select * from sys.databases` shows, like SSMS, that the **master** database has a `user_access_desc` set to `SINGLE_USER`.

However, executing `sp_helpdb 'master'` says it is in `MULTI_USER` mode.

Nothing problematic noticed on the server. I can access server and master database through multiple threads.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 
Run the

```
ALTER DATABASE master
SET MULTI_USER;
```

and confirm you receive the error *Option ‘MULTI_USER’ cannot be set in database ‘master’.*

Check your errorlog for any information that could explain why and when. 
Then

1. Backup the master database
2. Restore as a different database, example 'master_temp'.
3. Switch master_temp to MULTI_USER.
4. Backup master_temp.
5. Restore master with the backup of master_temp.

Comment: I was on a call with Microsoft for some other issue and asked them about this problem. Their answer was the same. Thanks.